# Explain the difference between the result got from Spark approxQuantile function and percentile_approx

Tags: apache-spark, hive

When I run the code below, I got the result: Quantiles segments =WrappedArray(-27.0, 2.0, 4443.0), which shows the median is 2.0

val quantiles = dfQuestions
.stat
.approxQuantile("score",Array(0,0.5,1.0),0.25)
println(s"Quantiles segments =${quantiles.toSeq}")

Quantiles segments =WrappedArray(-27.0, 2.0, 4443.0)

When I used the percentile_approx(score, 0.25), I got the same result. Can anyone tell me why is 0.25 used in here, not 0.5

dfQuestions.createOrReplaceTempView("so_questions")
sparkSession.sql("select min(score), percentile_approx(score, 0.25), max(score) from so_questions").show()

Answer (score 0):

So first, I am getting an error when I try code resembling yours:

```
NameError: name 'Array' is not defined
```

Replacing your Array() with brackets [] works although I removed your first argument of 0 because that yielded:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o257.approxQuantile.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

This is odd because the [Apache Spark webpage](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile.html) for **pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile()** indicates 0 for the *probabilities* argument captures the minimum. Perhaps this is a versioning issue.

Anyhow, this worked:

```
dfQuestions.stat.approxQuantile("score", [0.5,1.0], 0.25)
```

Nevertheless, assuming both `approxQuantile()` and `percentile_approx()` are operating as expected then it is possible that the 0.25 percentile and 0.5 percentile (*median*) are the same. For example, they are equivalent in this list of 12 values:

```
0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4
```

The 0.25 percentile is the fourth value = 2 (1/3 of values below 2) and the 0.5 percentile is between the sixth (2) and seventh (2) values, which is 2 because they are equivalent.

Lastly, I allow that the approximations may not be working as expected. I have experienced more accurate results with `percentile_approx()`, even with a *relativeError* argument of 0 (*exact calculation*) instead of your 0.25 for `approxQuantile()`. The inaccuracy of an "exact calculation" does not make sense. I may be making an unknown mistake somewhere.

I use `percentile_approx()` in a SQL line a la:

```
score_quantile = sqlContext.sql("select percentile_approx(score, 0.25) as \
approx25Quantile from dfQuestions")
score_quantile.show()
```